# How to DELETE all data in a table except for rows with specifc words?

Tags: sql, delete-row, pgadmin-4

I am using pgadmin4 (version 2.1) and I'm attempting to remove some legacy data from a table without deleting rows with specific words in the description?

Basically I'm attempting to do something like this:

DELETE FROM schema.table
WHERE column_description = all data
EXCEPT FOR 'specific word'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to backup your data before attempting any deletes.  But the idea would be:

```
DELETE FROM schema.table
    WHERE column_description IS DISTINCT FROM 'specific word';
```

This does not delete `NULL` values.  If the column could have `NULL` values, you will want those deleted too.  So a better construct is:

```
DELETE FROM schema.table
    WHERE column_description <> 'specific word';
```

Or, if the pattern could be *part* of the description, use `NOT LIKE`:

```
DELETE FROM schema.table
    WHERE column_description NOT LIKE '%specific word%';
```